# Scraping a pathway

Tags: weight-painting, sculpting

[image]
So I want to scrape a pathway following the line, since I have cleared the path from grass with the weight painter.
Using the sculpt mode, when I start scraping, some weird "reverse" scrape is happening on the other end as shown here:
[image]
It seems it's kinda inverting what I'm trying to sculpt.

Any reasoning behind this? I am new to Blender and am trying to create a grass meadow with a path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In sculpt mode press 'T'.

In the menu on the left, under 'Symmetry Lock' click on the 'X' option to turn it off.

This causes all changes made on one side of the X-axis to be repeated on the other side of it. It's useful when you're sculpting symmetric objects.

Comment: @CasperEngl no problem, mate